# Polymer paper buttons not working inside chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, polymer, paper-elements

I'm trying to add some paper elements to a popup of a chrome extension.  So far so good as to rendering them in the popup but I'm having trouble having my buttons work.  Since Chrome extensions have to have separate files for the JavaScript here is the code I'm working with:

popup.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Popup</title>
  <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html">
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/font-roboto/roboto.html">
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-fab/paper-fab.html">
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-toast/paper-toast.html">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/popup.css">
</head>

<body unresolved style="width: 750px">

  <section>
      <template id="buttonGroup" is="auto-binding">
          <paper-button raised="" id="signin" role="button" tabindex="1" on-click="{{signIn}}">Sign in</paper-button>
          <paper-button raised="" id="signout" role="button" tabindex="2" on-click="{{signOut}}" class="red"  >Sign out</paper-button>
      </template>
  </section>

<script src="js/popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
Polymer({

var buttonIn = document.querySelector('signin');

  buttonIn.addEventListener('signin', function() {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({message: "do_signin"}, function(response) {});
  });

var buttonOut = document.querySelector('signout');

  buttonOut.addEventListener('signout', function() {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({message: "do_signout"}, function(response) {});
  });


});
```

The problem is Chrome is returning with the following `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` on the line `var buttonIn = document.querySelector('signin');`

Is this because of some problem between polymer and the chrome extension or because I'm doing something wrong?

P.S. When the button gets clicked, all I need it to do is send a message to the background.js file that will handle the signin/signout.

Comment: It's JS object not a function  for you to declare variable like this.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not very familiar with `Polymer`, it is clear that `Polymer` is expecting you to pass something other than a function, where you seem to be trying to pass in a function without properly declaring the function. Really, I think you should have *all* your scripts outside of `Polymer` like such:

```
Polymer();

var buttonIn = document.getElementById('signin');

  buttonIn.addEventListener('signin', function() {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({message: "do_signin"}, function(response) {});
  });

var buttonOut = document.getElementById('signout');

  buttonOut.addEventListener('signout', function() {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({message: "do_signout"}, function(response) {});
  });
```

Also note that I changed `querySelector('signin')` to `getElementById('signin')` as you are looking for an element with an **id**. To use `querySelector` with an "id", prepend a "#" to "signin": `querySelector('#signin')`.

Check out the [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/polymer.html#imperativeregister) as to how to initiate Polymer.

Comment: Just a note: It might be a good idea to replace `querySelector` with `getElementById`.

Comment: @JonSnow, is there a benefit to using `getElementById`?

Comment: You may just mean it takes away from the confusion if you are new to DOM manipulation, which makes sense and we are obviously looking for an element with a certain id.

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys!  Now it's giving me `Uncaught Element name could not be inferred.` so when I looked it up it might have to do something with vulcanization? I'm not too sure since I've never dealt with this stuff before.

Comment: Yeah, read the documentation I provided. You need to tell Polymer which element you want to use. I hate reading too, but it's what you gotta do sometimes. :D

Comment: It makes it more readable and it _might_ be faster. But still this isn't a big deal.

EDIT: Apparently there's a benchmark: https://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector/11

Comment: I like it! Thanks for sharing @JonSnow. I think it's determined, should be `getElementById` :)